# Lambda Expression of Select * from TableName

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I just want to know what's the lambda expression of `Select * from TableName`.
Like in plain LINQ it will be `var res=from s in db.StudentDatas select s`;
here `StudentData` is name of the table.

Thanks.

Comment: Lambda expressions are anonymous functions, not queries. They are used as parts of queries though...

Comment: Why do questions like this get downvoted, when a simple explanation will suffice?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: becasue we live in a world of haters

Comment: I also detest downvoting without properly thinking first. I suppose those that does it get a "kick" of some sort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The lambda expression isn't needed:

```
var res = db.StudentDatas;
```

You could use one but it would be rather pointless:

```
var res = db.StudentDatas.Select(s => s);
```

Comment: It's not needed from a logical perspective, but if the compiler optimized out the Select() call then there would be no opportunity for LINQ to SQL to invoke the database query.

Comment: I will not use, but just wanted to know.Thanks for the expression.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what you're saying. The compiler wouldn't optimise out code that you need to run.

Comment: @Gary I interpreted Wondering's question as "what happens behind the scenes," not "what's the best way to do this."  What happens behind the scenes is that the 'select' keyword becomes a static method call on an IQueryable, whose argument is the lambda both of us gave in our answers.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will translate it to something along these lines:

```
db.StudentDatas.Select(s => s)
```

The translation to SQL is done by the Base Class Library.  SQL, of course, does not use lambda expressions...

Comment: what is "db." ?

Comment: Its the common variable name for DbContext

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't require a lambda expression.  You just want all members of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

While both are technically correct, as in they would both give the same result in its simplistic form, this is only because the default behavior of `db.table` is “Select”. Behind the scenes, they are different. While one is a `System.Data.Linq.Table`, the other is `System.Linq.IQuerable`.
For example

```
var x = db.table ; var y= db.table(s=>s); 
X = y;
```

would result in a compiler error.

When using the Dynamic Linq library, in cases where you have to create dynamic queries at runtime, you have to use an `IQuerable` as your initial select. Which means `var qry = db.table(s=>s);` as opposed to var `qry = db.table;`
Then you can go on and chain your queries like: `qry = qry.Where(bla bla bla);`

Found it out the hard way after a few nail biting sessions.

Answer (score -2):

Code:

```
var allmember = eg_.table.where(x=>x).ToList();
```